# Perl Script to run Junit test cases and unistall apk

Tags: android, eclipse, perl

What I want my Perl script to do is..

1. Run the specific Junit test cases from windows command line.
2. Uninstall the Apk file from android device or emulator.

I am having difficulty in getting started with 1.For step2 , I guess I can use

```
     adb uninstall package name
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to launch eclipse to run junit test cases.
Try running the Junit tests through script using command line.
More information here. http://www.jsystemtest.org/?q=node/44